# jQuery AJAX POST not recognized CakePHP 3

Tags: jquery, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

So, I have some simple code setup, I've reduced it to absolutely the bare essentials just for testing purposes. Here is my javascript:

```
$('a#delete').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.post($(this).attr('href'), $('input.delete:checked').serialize());
})
```

And here is my Controller code:

```
public function delete() {
    debug($this->request->is('ajax'));
    debug($this->request->is('post'));
    debug($this->request->data);
    die();
}
```

At the moment I have one checkbox I am using for testing:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="delete_portfolio" class="delete" value="15">
```

I have verified using Fiddler that it is sending a `POST` request with the data of "`delete_portfolio=15`". However, `$this->request->is('post')` is returning false, even though that's exactly what's being sent. And `$this->request->data` is empty. Funny thing is that `$this->request->is('get')` actually returns true, but `$this->request->query` is still empty.

I'm just trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong sending an `AJAX POST` request to Cake.

**EDIT**

I just wanted to include some new information I found here. I ended up adding:

```
debug($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']);
debug($_POST);
```

To my controller code to see what PHP was seeing for the request method, turns out it returns `'POST'` as expected and returns the correct data, so it's only CakePHP 3 that's not seeing it as POST and isn't seeing the data, perhaps this is a bug?

Comment: $('a#delete') shouldn't this be an ID asign to an <a href> and in your HTML I see input with a class of "delete" instead of ID. I can't imagine how u manage to get the value in a GET request as u said.

Comment: So, the problem isn't with the click event not working. As I stated in the question I can see the POST request with Fiddler, along with the data. And I reported what I was getting back from my controller, which is also receiving the request. I didn't include the link that I am clicking in my HTML as I felt that irrelevant, as the problem is not with the click event.

Comment: Check the `REQUEST_METHOD` [**server var**](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php), if it's not `POST` while you are definitely sending a `POST` request, then your server/php installation needs one or two bitchslaps.

Comment: The `REQUEST_METHOD` server var is `GET`. And no data is in the data or query parameters. Not sure if bitchslap is a technical term in this case :P, or you have an actual suggestion I can use :P.

Comment: what if you do it thisd way $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});

Comment: Sorry, I had tried that as well previously, I switched to the .post as it was a more concise way of doing the identical thing.

Comment: Well, I'd say bitchslapping your server is next to trying to turn it off and on again :) But for an actual, real suggestion, start with trying another browser, I remember such a bug in an old Chrome version, then check whether your server maybe uses `FastCGI`, if I recall correctly, there are situations where data might get modified when it's being forwarded internally. Also check for `HTTP_X_HTTP_METHOD_OVERRIDE` being present, this, as well as the `_method` field (in the POST data) can overwrite the request method (look for `ORIGINAL_REQUEST_METHOD`).

Comment: ps, don't forget to use @username tags to make sure the one you are "talking" to get's notified, I just saw your response by chance.

Comment: @ndm I didn't realize that, thank you. As to your suggestions, I tested on Chrome, IE 11, and Firefox (all latest versions), and I get the same result from all of them. The only headers being sent are all expected, no `HTTP_X_HTTP_METHOD_OVERRIDE`. There is no `_method` field in the POST data. My server is using FastCGI, however I've had no issues previous to this with any other submitted data from real forms (not ajax submitted). Nor did I have any problems with this in CakePHP 2.6, which is what I'm upgrading from.

Comment: @ndm I added new information to my question that I found by debugging some server variables that get set in a request.

Comment: @ndm I just realized that previously I had told you that the `REQUEST_METHOD` server var was `GET`. This was incorrect, the `REQUEST_METHOD` parameter inside the Cake request object was set to `GET`, as is the `ORIGINAL_REQUEST_METHOD`. The actual server var `REQUEST_METHOD` is set to `POST`, as I highlighted in my above edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally figured out what was wrong, and something that should definitely be considered for everyone else. I had the Security Component enabled, which was redirecting unsecured requests (ajax) to a secure request (https). Because this redirect was happening, it was changing my request to a GET request and blackholing me as my form had been altered. To fix this:

```
$this->Security->config('unlockedActions', ['delete']);
```

Was added to my controller's `beforeFilter` function.